# How to overwrite bootstrap css correctly?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I have a global stylesheet `modal.scss` for restyling default bootstrap's model. I want to centre the model footer with `justify-content: center;` But it is not applying because of bootstraps folder `_modal.scss` which is setted to `justify-content: flex-end;`
*How can I overwrite this, or I have to make changes in `_modal.scss`* ?

```
    .modal-footer {
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: $color-dashboard-background;
        border-top: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

Comment: add your own style at bottom of page , so first default style execute and then your style , in-short your style will overwrite.

Comment: It is imported/included in correct order in `angular.json` file but not applying.

Comment: in your design file html , call <style> tag at end of page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redesign the whole bootstrap component then you can use bootstrap's customization option. You can update the bootstrap's existing sass variables with your preferred values.

Here is the link to the documentation if you'd like to try it.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can use "!important" on that particular property and it will overwrite the bootstrap property.

```
.modal-footer {
        justify-content: center!important;
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: $color-dashboard-background;
        border-top: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

Comment: Using !important is not a good option. It can overwrite some important styles from the base CSS file.